# Limit of function of two variable.

Tags: calculus, limits

How to find the following limit

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{xy}{x+y}$$

I like to use squeeze but not getting in proper way as $x$ and $y$ may be of different sign . Help me. Thanks.

Comment: polar coordinates may help

Comment: $x=rcos\theta$, $y=rsin\theta$ then?

Comment: The limit does not exist. For (i) approach along $y=0$ and (ii) approach along $y=x^2-x$.

Comment: yes i got ...thanks a lot..

Comment: @tired Unfortunately, polar coordinates doesn't directly help here.

Comment: $y = mx + q$ and the result is then zero.

Comment: you might also argue on the fact that approaching to zero, $xy$ goes to zero faster than $x+y$.

Comment: are you saying that limit exist and equal to zero? but it does't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a problem in that the function is not defined everywhere near $(0,0)$. If we have $x=-y$, then we're dividing by zero, as you mention.

Near this line of undefined-ness, the function becomes unbounded, so even if we ignore it, the limit fails to exist. But it is interesting to note that approaching the origin through any other *straight* line will yield limit zero. To show this, use polar coordinates, as a user suggested.